# Make wget link-rewrite aware of all downloaded files

Tags: wget

After downloading a tutorial via

```
wget -r -l 1 -k -nd -p http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html
```

`wget` rewrites (`-k`) the link of all the documents on the index.html page to point to local links downloaded via `-r -l 1`. This tutorial consists of three pages, with a link from page 1 to page 2 (and from page 2 to page 3), so the "structure" is

- index

  - page 1 (links to page 2)
  - page 2 (links to page 3)
  - page 3

The link on page 1 to page 2 is not rewritten to the local page 2-file, even though `wget` downloaded page 2.

Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The link given is a list of tutorials, and not a link to check for the actual problem your having.

I would suggest based on the base file in your example is

> /index.html

which is in its own directory and assuming links will be in that directory as well, Try this:

```
    wget -m -k -p http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial
         or
    wget -m -k -p http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/
```

instead of using

```
    wget -r -l ( recourse | level)
```

use

> -m or mirror option which is a shortcut for -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing 
>   
>   remove the -nd     ( no host directories )

which could lead to issues for any css pictures etc that are needed to make page work even though your using -k

Comment: This increased the download size by several orders of magnitude (I aborted when it started to DL the huge pdf). Is there a way to avoid that?